# Determining sample size n for a plant experiment

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I am testing plant health by looking at height, stem width, color, and content (antioxidants and the like). However, I was unsure how to determine a sample size for each measurement, in order to have results that are statistically significant. That is in each pot, how many stems should I measure? In each type of plant, how many plants should I measure? I wasn't sure which distribution to use here either, so if someone could explain which distribution works best, and why, I would appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 'which distribution to use/works best' part of the question is not clear. Distribution of data, unknown and impossible to choose, or distribution of sampling effort?

Comment: What tests are you performing? You'll need to specify effect sizes and the power you want at those effect sizes, as well as significance level.

Answer (score 1):

If you have prior (literature-based or preliminary) data for estimating the range of variation you could calculate n for a desired effect size for each treatment eg http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html or (a bit of a cheat) http://www.statisticalsolutions.net/pss_calc.php

Or do a simulation as suggested here [Sample size calculation for mixed models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48374/sample-size-calculation-for-mixed-models), particularly if you have a more complex design (plant type x treatment x (?) blocked by pot).

However, it is likely that the treatment is applied to the entire pot, which is, therefore, your experimental unit. If this is the case, measuring more plants per pot would be pseudoreplication.

Having different sample sizes for different response variables within the same (presumably) experiment will be a red flag for reviewers, so you would normally choose the same sample size for all measurements - if going into trouble of having more replicates, might as well

Finally, at least some of the response variables could be correlated (height and stem width; color and *content(?!)*), so it may be worth using one of each pair or combining them into composites to reduce the correction for multiple tests. PS You may want to re-state the question to ‘having the power to detect a certain effect size’ vs. ‘have results that are statistically significant’ which sounds a bit biased.