# Repeated measures ANOVA study - calculating the sample size

Tags: anova

I’m soon conducting a study on healthy volunteers. I’m interested to know how 3 different body positions is going to affect the cross-sectional area of a neck vein measured by ultrasound. (Primary outcome). For each participant, I will measure the area 3 times, once in each position.

I'm planning to use the RM-ANOVA for analysis.

How can i calculate the sample size that I need?

From literature review, I found that the mean area of this vein is 124 +/- 46mm2. Assuming 25% increase is clinically significant. P <0.05 is significant.

Any help would be appreciated ! (I want to know how it is calculated, e.g. using G Power, rather than just the answer)
Cheers.

Comment: This question may help but it won't help with with how to do it in G Power, something I doubt you'll get much help on this forum for.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48374/sample-size-calculation-for-mixed-models